# Don't understand the use of そして + に in a sentence

Tags: particle-に

I just received an answer from a Japanese friend about a video I sent her.  The video shows my dog doing stuff.  She answered with, among other things, these two sentences:

本当にかわいくて、かしこい犬です。そしてに白い足がとてもかわいい！！

I understand the meaning of そしてused at the beginning of a sentence, similar to それから but without the chronological order implication.  I don't understand why she used に after it, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's most likely a typo. Maybe she typed それに白い first and then made it そして but forgot to delete the に.